# Can I play my unity VR application using RiftCat

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, steamvr

I am new to VR application development with unity using SteamVR. I haven't the capability to buy an expensive headset for my studies. So Can I test my unity application with RiftCat.

Comment: Why haven't you tried it yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Mixed Reality Simulator allows you to run UWP and SteamVR applications and use virtual motion controllers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-the-windows-mixed-reality-simulator

Comment: Thank Will. It is useful for me